# Save File Dialog Csharp

Tags: c#, visual-studio

me gustaría conocer alguna forma de guardar automáticamente un archivo cada cierto tiempo de manera automatizada sin interactuar para el guardado mediante ningún botón. Es decir que se sobreescriba automáticamente el archivo cada cierto tiempo.

Tengo una aplicación de windows forms en la que recojo datos de un sensor y hasta ahora los guardo mediante un botón con save file dialog y como digo me gustaría automatizarlo cada cierto tiempo, dos horas por ejemplo, reescribiéndose el archivo anteriormente guardado.

Gracias.

```
   private void guardar_button(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sfd.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void sfd_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        string nombre = sfd.FileName;
        File.WriteAllText(nombre, txtLog.Text);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes intentar con un [`Timer`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8) haciendo que se ejecute cada 2 horas:

```
Timer t = new Timer(GuardarArchivo, null, 0, TimeSpan.FromHours(2));

private static void GuardarArchivo(Object o) {
     // codigo para guardar el archivo
}
```

Esto siempre y cuando el programa no se cierre porque de lo contrario tendras que hacer un servicio.

Comment: El tema está en que después de la primera vez en que se selecciona el archivo, necesito que se autoguarde, sin que se muestre el ShowDialog(), no se si me explico.

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer bastante sencillo con un *timer* global que lanzará un evento cada cierto tiempo (el tiempo se define en milisegundos y 7.200.000 milisegundos son 2 horas).

En ese evento puedes guardar el fichero como ya haces, verificando que tienes el nombre de fichero (que también debes declarar con el alcance adecuado).

Te adjunto el código que yo haría más o menos (siempre se puede comprobar alguna cosa más, pero básicamente seria esto):

```
        private static Timer unTimer;
        private string nombreGlobal;
        //2 h * 60 minutos * 60 segundos * 1000 milisegundos = 7200000
        private int milisegundos = 7200000 

    void inicializaDialogo()
    {        
        unTimer = new Timer(milisegundos);
        unTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timeElapsed);
    }

    private void sfd_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        nombreGlobal = sfd.FileName;
        File.WriteAllText(nombreGlobal, txtLog.Text);
    }


    public void timeElapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(nombreGlobal))){
            File.WriteAllText(nombreGlobal, txtLog.Text);
        } else {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Lleva {0} minutos funcionando sin guardar _
            los datos. Indique un archivo y posteriormente el guardado será automático",_ 
            (milisegundos/60000) ), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

PD.: Gran parte lo he escrito aquí directamente, así que puede haber algún error de sintaxis

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado con un timer y el siguiente código, el archivo se guarda automáticamente según el tiempo que marque en el timer.

```
  private void tsbGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
        string nombre = sfd.FileName;
        if (File.Exists(nombre))
        {

            File.WriteAllText(nombre, txtLog.Text);

        }
        else
        {
            sfd.ShowDialog();

        }
    }

    private void sfd_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        string nombre = sfd.FileName;
        File.WriteAllText(nombre, txtLog.Text);
```